# Quick documentation for Pandas column objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed that my IDE, Pycharm, doesn't offer quick documentation (for instance, showing me the description of a function after I type it) for some Pandas objects.

If I have a column in a dataframe and want to remember what kinds of operations I can make to it, such as `.str.lower()`, `.str` doesn't appear as one of the options after I type in the period.

Ideas/suggestions?

Comment: This might be helpful!! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#  Have a look at `Working with Text Data` section.

Comment: Try settings/editor/general/code completions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but; Ctrl + Space works for me. Sometimes hit Ctrl + Space twice to get the suggestions open.
Hints on the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html) Code Completion Web page.

Have you used Conda?